# How to pass data between pages in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have a Next.js app which has multiple pages. Each page has the same bar at the top of the screen which displays some data which is fetched from an internal API using SWR. The issue I am having is that to fetch that data it requires an ID of the logged in user (they log in with Discord via `next-auth`) and after they have left the first page, that ID value is no longer accessible to me.

I have tired storing it in local storage and session storage, I have tried passing it through other components, but nothing has worked and I am out of ideas of how to fix this. Is there any other way where I can pass a value between pages? Or is there a way I can access the session data again?

Comment: Well, you can always access the session data with next auth's `useSession` hook. What I understand is that you need a layout component that is shared between all pages. You can create it, wrap your whole app in `_app.js` and fetch that data on the layout component using the user's id obtained from `useSession`.

Comment: I tried using `useSession` in my other page but it just returned `undefined` every time. Layouts seem the way to go, I will have to do some research into that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use this on all pages, you could just add that header into the `_app.{js,tsx}`(see the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)). In case you don't I suppose you create a layout component and reuse it across these pages.

In the future we might be able to use the new Routing API which allows passing adding Layout components for certain sub-routes. (Check the [Layout RFC](https://nextjs.org/blog/layouts-rfc) for more info).

Answer (score 0):

because next js uses the  react library so you can pass the data using props or you can use redux as well.
like this:
`<Component propName={value}/>`